# Symfony - Unique entity in CollectionType field?

Tags: symfony, validation, collections, constraints, unique

I have a formBuilder that contains a collectionType. I would like to be able to put a constraint on the email field to be sure that when the user validates, there is not the same email address several times in the form

I've :

**RegistrationCollectionType.php**

```
$builder
        ->add('utilisateurs', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => RegistrationType::class,
            'entry_options' => [
                'label' => false,
                'entreprise' => $entreprise,
            ],
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'delete_empty' => true,
            'by_reference' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'label' => false,
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'my-selector',
                'label' => false,
            ],
            'by_reference' => false,
        ])
        ;
```

With his class :

**RegistrationCollection.php**

```
class RegistrationCollection
{


    private $utilisateurs = [];

    public function getUtilisateurs(): ?array
    {
        return $this->utilisateurs;
    }

    public function setUtilisateurs(?array $utilisateurs): self
    {
        $this->utilisateurs = $utilisateurs;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And in my **RegistrationType.php** which is associated with my **User** entity, I've :

**RegistrationType.php**

```
->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => "Adresse email"
                ],
            ])
```

[image]

Now if I valid, I've :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicata du
>   champ 'ahahs@mail.fr' pour la clef 'UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I kept the idea of a custom constraint, but which would not apply only to emails but to any field that we want Unique:

```
#App\Validator\Constraints\UniqueProperty.php

<?php

namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class UniqueProperty extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'This collection should contain only elements with uniqe value.';
    public $propertyPath;

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return UniquePropertyValidator::class;
    }
}
```

and

```
#App\Validator\Constraints\UniquePropertyValidator.php

<?php

namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedValueException;

class UniquePropertyValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor
     */
    private $propertyAccessor;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->propertyAccessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $value
     * @param Constraint $constraint
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!$constraint instanceof UniqueProperty) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, UniqueProperty::class);
        }

        if (null === $value) {
            return;
        }

        if (!\is_array($value) && !$value instanceof \IteratorAggregate) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException($value, 'array|IteratorAggregate');
        }

        if ($constraint->propertyPath === null) {
            throw new \Exception('Option propertyPath can not be null');
        }

        $propertyValues = [];
        foreach ($value as $key => $element) {
            $propertyValue = $this->propertyAccessor->getValue($element, $constraint->propertyPath);
            if (in_array($propertyValue, $propertyValues, true)) {

                $message = sprintf("%s (%s)", $constraint->message, $propertyValue);

                $this->context->buildViolation($message)
                    // ->atPath(sprintf('[%s]', $key))
                    ->atPath(sprintf('[%s][%s]', $key, $constraint->propertyPath))
                    ->addViolation();
            }

            $propertyValues[] = $propertyValue;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
class RegistrationCollection
{


    /**
     * @App\UniqueProperty(
     *      message = "Adresse mail déjà utilisée",
     *      propertyPath = "email"
     * )
     *
     */
    private $utilisateurs = [];
```

It works very well, except that I can't target the child field for the error. Systematically, the error will go to the parent entity, and therefore the error will be put all over it.

I tried in the validator to redirect to the fields of the child entity concerned, but nothing to do, the error continues to put everything above..

[image]

[image]

In my FormType I tried to disable **error_bubbling** but same thing

```
->add('utilisateurs', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => RegistrationType::class,
            'entry_options' => [
                'label' => false,
                'entreprise' => $entreprise,
            ],
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'delete_empty' => true,
            'by_reference' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'label' => false,
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'my-selector',
                'label' => false,
            ],
            'by_reference' => false,
            'error_bubbling' => false,
        ])
        ;
```

Comment: Thanks for this! To target the child field `->atPath(sprintf('[%s].%s', $key, $constraint->propertyPath))` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom validation constraint

```
class UniqueEmailValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!$constraint instanceof UniqueEmail) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, UniqueEmail::class);
        }

        if (!\is_array($value) && !$value instanceof \IteratorAggregate) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException($value, 'array|IteratorAggregate');
        }

        $emails = [];
        foreach ($value as $element) {
            if (\in_array($element->getEmail(), $emails, true)) {
                $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                    ->addViolation();

                return;
            }

            $emails[] = $element->getEmail();
        }
    }
}
```

and add to your property a validation annotation

```
class RegistrationCollection
{

    /**
     * @AppAssert\UniqueEmailValidator
     */
    private $utilisateurs = [];

    public function getUtilisateurs(): ?array
    {
        return $this->utilisateurs;
    }

    public function setUtilisateurs(?array $utilisateurs): self
    {
        $this->utilisateurs = $utilisateurs;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I kept your idea but I make a new answer to give more details

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version added this, but you don't have to create a class to add a simple validating contstraint:

1. define a validate method on your Form(Type) class

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
// ...
    public function validateYourField(
        $yourFieldInput,
        ExecutionContextInterface $context,
        array $payload,
    ): void
    {
        // do some validation
        if (someCondition) {
            // if valid => just return void
            return;
        }

        // if not valid => add violation
        $context->buildViolation('some error message')
            ->atPath('yourField')
            ->addViolation();
    }
```

2. add the constraint reference

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
// ...
    ->add(
        'yourField',
        // ...
        [
            // ...
            'constraints' => [
                new Assert\Callback(
                    $this->validateYourField(...),
                    payload: $someCustomData,
                ),
        ],
    ])
```

**Note:** three dots here `$this->validateYourField(...)` is NOT a typo NOR a comment! it's how you reference a method as a callback in newer versions of PHP :-)

As you can guess, you don't even have to create a named method, you can simply put some anonymous callback instead, but if it's too long, it is better to have it in a named method.